# How do you create the effect that voices are mumbled while the character is daydreaming in a comic panel?

Tags: comics

How do you create the effect that voices are mumbled while the character is daydreaming in a comic panel? In films, you actually hear the mumbled voices while the character is daydreaming or in a sort of trance-like state. How do you achieve this in a comic panel? Is this even possible? What are some ways of achieving similar effects?

Comment: Are the voices mumbled or are they just out of focus of the viewpoint character?

Comment: The voices can't be heard by the character daydreaming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen a couple of techniques used.

### Blurry text

It's the text equivalent of the lack of camera focus that you see in movies. I've seen it a lot when a character is either groggily waking up or getting knocked out. I've also seen it used in a bit of a different context, to [show that a character is drunk](https://www.webtoons.com/en/romance/lore-olympus/episode-4/viewer?title_no=1320&episode_no=4).

Sometimes the text is legible for anyone who squints enough, other times it's too obscured to determine so it could just be nonsense blurred.

### Squiggle lines

A line like a long tilde is drawn in the speech bubble. Used for background noise in several different contexts (e.g. talking in a crowd or too far away).

[image: squiggles far off in the distance]

Source: [Half-Ghost Episode 58](https://www.webtoons.com/en/romance/half-ghost/episode-58/viewer?title_no=2765&episode_no=59)

### "Mumble"

While novel writing eschews having this type of thing, comics seem to embrace it. (You'll also see "ha ha ha" in a speech bubble for a laughing character.) Obviously you're only going to see "mumble" in a speech bubble where the character is mumbling.

[image: woman "mumble"s on couch]

Source: [Half-Ghost Episode 57](https://www.webtoons.com/en/romance/half-ghost/episode-57/viewer?title_no=2765&episode_no=58)